# Why does OnCollisionEnter not get triggered?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have got two objects:

Object A (SteamVR Camera):

- Has a Rigidbody with "Is Kinematic" enabled.
- Has a Box Collider with "Is Trigger" enabled.
- Has the Script with the "OnCollisionEnter" method.

Object B (Globe model):

- Has a Sphere Collider with "Is Trigger" enabled.

I made sure that the collider ranges are correctly, but somehow the OnCollisionEnter method does not get triggered.

The code that I am using for OnCollisionEnter looks like below:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision entered");
}
```

Could someone provide me some insight/advice?

Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 5):

### ISSUE: there's no collision between any object with a Trigger

To understand how collision works you need first to identify which objects are colliding, because very few objects may trigger [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).

From your description we can identify 2 types of objects.

> **Object A**: Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider
>   **Object B**: Static Trigger Collider

If you check the [Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) there could be no collision with anything that has a Trigger (both Object A and Object B), so OnCollisionEnter won't fire.
I repeat: a Trigger does not collide with anything no matter what the other object is.

### SOLUTION: Use OnTriggerEnter instead of OnCollisionEnter

If you want to get the event from a collision with a trigger objects (or 2 of them, like in your case) you can use [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html).

Consider that in this case the parameter of the method will be `Collider other` that is a [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) instead of a [Collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html), but in your case I think you won't need the collision at all.

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    => Debug.Log("entered");
```

---

### INSIGHTS about Unity collisions

The collisions depend on the rigidbody and collider setup objects. I can show a few examples based on your situation.

The first element to consider is that Static Collider is not an usual Object set as Static (this was a source of confusion in the comments below).

From [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

> **STATIC COLLIDER**
>   This is a GameObject that has a Collider but no Rigidbody. Static
>   colliders are used for level geometry which always stays at the same
>   place and never moves around. Incoming rigidbody objects will collide
>   with the static collider but will not move it.

Consider also that you want to use a trigger (that makes your STATIC COLLDER into a STATIC TRIGGER COLLIDER).

Basically the idea behind trigger is:
*"Use triggers when you want to catch the event but you don't want the gameobject interacting with Physics forces."*

### Triggers

> The scripting system can detect when collisions occur and initiate
>   actions using the OnCollisionEnter function. However, **you can also use
>   the physics engine simply to detect when one collider enters the space
>   of another without creating a collision**. **A collider configured as a
>   Trigger (using the Is Trigger property) does not behave as a solid
>   object and will simply allow other colliders to pass through**. When a
>   collider enters its space, a trigger will call the OnTriggerEnter
>   function on the trigger object’s scripts

Comment: I don't see in the question where either object is Static. The Collision Matrix has a `Y` where `Kinematic Rigidbody Collider` meets `Rigidbody Trigger Collider`

Comment: From what I read we have a static collider (that is a GameObjec that has a ColliderTrigger and no rigidbody) with a Trigger vs Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider.

Comment: Static is for the object itself. It's a checkbox in the top right of the inspector. Static, kinematic, and rigidbodies are not mutually exclusive since they are driven individually.

Comment: I'm citing [unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) Static Collider: This is a GameObject that has a Collider but no Rigidbody.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for pointing that out. OP would not be able to use OnCollisionEnter with triggers regardless