# Collider not registering on prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

Hello I'm having an issue with my colliders registering. My two prefabs collide with each other and the environment but I am trying to program my game so that when the enemy touches the player, the player loses damage but there is no lowering in damage occurring. My debug logs show that the computer isn't even registering the collider at all. Any help is appreciated thanks! I have rigidbodies on both prefabs as well as capsule and box colliders.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Mirror;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
CharacterController characterController;

public float speed = 6.0f;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
public float gravity = 20.0f;
public int maxHealth = 30;
public int currentHealth;
public GameObject myPrefab;
public int damage = 10;

Transform cameraTransform;
private GambeObject HealthBar = Find;

private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

void Start()
{
    myPrefab.transform.Rotate(0.0f ,0.0f ,0.0f );
    Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 5), Quaternion.identity);
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    currentHealth = maxHealth;
    FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>().SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
  //  FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>().SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
  //  cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
}

void TakeDamage(int damage) {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>().SetHealth(currentHealth);
      //  FindObjectOfType<HealthBar>().SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
          Debug.Log("collision statement");
      if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy"){
          currentHealth-=damage;
          Debug.Log("Snowman Collision detected");
      }

 }

void Update()
{

  if (isLocalPlayer){

    if (characterController.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, 
        Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection *= speed;

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
    }


    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
    }

  }

public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
   {

       Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().setTarget(gameObject.transform);
   }
```

}

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360902/why-does-oncollisionenter-not-get-triggered/56361120#56361120

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does OnCollisionEnter not get triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360902/why-does-oncollisionenter-not-get-triggered)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your character collider settings in editor carefully? Uncheck **IsTrigger**.
Setup collider carefully.

[Collider.OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) Note: Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody. If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component.

Check if you have something missing. According to your code I guess you missing IMPORTANT point. Your snowman collider not trigger, it is a enemy character and interact with world without passing in it, also this applies to your character too. Then you should use [Collider.OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

Comment: yes I am not missing anything according to your reply. I changed the code to OnCollisionEnter and still no success :/

Comment: Maybe my post wasn't clear I linked **Collider.OnTrigger() and Note part from Unity Help** just because showing what you using wrong. You should use **Collider.OnCollisionEnter** and disable IsTrigger for both object.  Both object should have Rigidbody and proper colliders. Also when you play the game and characters visually appear collided, in Unity Editor show collider for both character and check if they are really colliding.

Comment: My collision debug logs now show up but my health bar is not losing health from the collisions. Thank you for your help sofar

Comment: In which part of code Debug.Log works. Right after collision detected **Debug.Log("collision statement");**? Is your code ever reach **currentHealth-=damage;** part? Make sure enemy has Enemy tag on runtime too. Make sure damage is not 0 too. Otherwise there shouldn't be problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally! I needed to change the line "currentHealth -= damage" to "TakeDamage(10);" Thanks so much everyone for your help :D